# Connecting a Mac OS up to a wireless network without a wireless card

Tags: mac, wireless-router, airport, airport-express

I have a Mac that doesn't have an airport. Is it possible to connect (via ethernet) the Mac to an airport express, which would communicate with another airport express in another room, which is connected to my broadband router?

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you that it's quite possible on a technical basis. The airport express should be able to be configured as a bridge, or a WDS node, and in either case it should both expand network coverage, and provide the same connection via the Ethernet port.

Client mode is not suitable for this, as it's designed to allow the airport express to serve as a print server, without using the Ethernet port.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2272?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Having looked further into the matter, WDS is the only method Apple supports. WDS requires reconfiguring both airports involved as described in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4262 setting up one "remote" station and one "main" station.

Answer (score 1):

If they are the same variety (age/model/firmware) of Airport Expresses, then yes. You need to configure them using the Airport Utility. There are lots of hidden options in the utility accessible by using the "alt" key when you click on the various options. Depending on age you will be going either for "Bridge" mode or WDS mode. Be aware that "Bridge" mode will shut out everything running wirelessly from the up-stream AE.
If they are different flavours then you may have to do a lot of fiddling to check that they are both using the same wireless (b or g or n) and have a mutual functionality. This may cause problems for other stuff using the upstream AE.
I(n) m(y) h(umble) o(pinion) an ethernet cable is a very efficient and cheap method of data transfer. It's also rather more secure.

Comment: We are currently using Ethernet for this connection, but as it's for a home system it's a bit awkward to have a long wire coming out of an upstairs room, across the landing and down the stairs to the router.